# nodejs 404 file not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I dont know why I am encountering this error, I double check the endpoint on my code and its match on the api tester, did I miss something?

Properties.js

```
  ....
  api: '/api',
  ....
```

My controller

```
const baseUrl = `${Properties.api}/form`
router.post(`${baseUrl}/SaveForm`, saveForm);
module.exports = router;

async function saveForm(req,res,next){
    let params = req.body;//post
    console.log(params)
}
```

my api tester

[image]

result

[image]

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: Did you mount the route in the main file?

Comment: What is the value of Properties.api ?